# create-react-app and url base path for the development server

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

during development, I'd like to use an already existing test server, this server uses apache, so I basically used mod_proxy to proxy it to a subdirectory of my server, let's say http://myserver/myreactapp/ 
Problem is, I didnt find a way to tell the development server that the js shouldnt be in

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>
```

but in

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myreactapp/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>
```

or more logically, in a relative path. I found this option for the build, but not the development server. what is a good way of achieving that ?

Comment: If you use nginx, you can use alias `location /static/ { alias /myreactapp/static/; }`. I do not know is anything like this for apache.

Comment: I suppose there's a way to do that with apache, I'll check mod_proxy's documentation

Comment: I added the answer for apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **nginx**, you can use [alias](https://nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) like this:

```
location /static/ {
  alias /myreactapp/static/;
}
```

If you use **apache**, the [alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) syntax is:

```
Alias "/static" "/myreactapp/static"
```

Comment: It works, but I'll have to find another solution soon, because my goal is to have more than one app proxied, so more than one static directory ^^